# Avoid full table scan with SELECT using PL/SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle19c

**Test data**

```
CREATE TABLE parent AS ( SELECT ROWNUM AS id, 'XXX' AS dummy FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 1000 );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_parent ON parent(id);

CREATE TABLE child AS ( SELECT CEIL(ROWNUM/5) AS id, 'XXX' AS dummy FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5000 );
CREATE INDEX idx_child ON child(id);

EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'parent');
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'child');
```

---

**Problem**

The following query does a full table scan (both with 12.1 and 19.0) on child even though the *CARDINALITY* hint is considered.
Of course the real query needs some additional data from child.

```
SELECT child.id
FROM parent
JOIN
(
    SELECT child.id
    FROM child
    GROUP BY child.id
) child ON ( child.id = parent.id )
WHERE parent.id IN ( SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY( tab 1 ) */ COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (sys.odcinumberlist(1) ) tab );
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |            |     1 |    19 |    35   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI                  |            |     1 |    19 |    35   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |     1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |            |  1000 | 17000 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    VIEW                                |            |  1000 | 13000 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     HASH GROUP BY                      |            |  1000 |  4000 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | CHILD      |  5000 | 20000 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                   | IDX_PARENT |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Both indexes are used as expected if I replace the *WHERE* clause by this:

```
WHERE parent.id IN ( 1 );
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |            |     5 |    35 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS       |            |     5 |    35 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN | IDX_PARENT |     1 |     4 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   VIEW              |            |     5 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    SORT GROUP BY    |            |     5 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN| IDX_CHILD  |     5 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It also works when I remove the `GROUP BY`.

---

Any idea how to work around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the required behviour using the [`MERGE` hint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#BABHIFDA)

```
SELECT child.id
FROM parent
JOIN
(
    SELECT /*+ MERGE */ child.id  ---<<<<< merge the subquery
    FROM child
    GROUP BY child.id
) child ON ( child.id = parent.id )
WHERE parent.id IN ( SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY( tab 1 ) */ COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (sys.odcinumberlist(1) ) tab );
```

The execution plan is as follows

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |            |     5 |    70 |    32   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                            |            |     5 |    70 |    32   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                            |            |     5 |    70 |    31   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                           |            |     1 |    10 |    30   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     SORT UNIQUE                           |            |     1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |     1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | IDX_PARENT |     1 |     8 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | IDX_CHILD  |     5 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   6 - access("PARENT"."ID"=VALUE(KOKBF$))
   7 - access("CHILD"."ID"="PARENT"."ID")
```

I guess your child table is too small that the CBO does not consider this plan as the best one; but it can have also other reasons.

**Additional Note**

There is a rather big difference between the predicates

```
parent.id IN ( subquery )   and

parent.id IN ( 1 )
```

In the latter case Oracle simple can *push the predicate* (`access("CHILD"."ID"=1)`) in the `group by` subquery. (see hint [PUSH_PRED](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#BABHAAJE)).

But anyway  if you **1)** know that the subquery returns only one row and **2)** you help a little with the predicate the Oracle CBO gets it right *without hints*

Here the slightly changed query according to 1) and 2) - see comments

```
SELECT child.id
FROM parent
JOIN
(
    SELECT child.id
    FROM child
    GROUP BY child.id
) child ON ( child.id = parent.id )
WHERE child.id  /* 2) match with *child.id* to help Oracle to unnest */
 =  /* 1) use equal predicate as there is ony one row */
( SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY( tab 1 ) */ COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE (sys.odcinumberlist(1) ) tab );
```

The plan

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |            |     5 |    85 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                             |            |     5 |    85 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW                                    |            |     5 |    65 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                          |            |     5 |    25 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | IDX_CHILD  |     5 |    25 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|            |     1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | IDX_PARENT |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - access("CHILD"."ID"= (SELECT /*+ OPT_ESTIMATE (TABLE "TAB"@"SEL$4" ROWS=1.000000 ) */ 
              VALUE(KOKBF$) FROM TABLE() "KOKBF$0"))
   6 - access("CHILD"."ID"="PARENT"."ID")
```

Comment: While this does not help for my original query (more complex), it works great for the one in my question. My original tables contain more data, and a similar query went from cost 96,000 to a cost of 58 with that hint. Looks like the optimizer did not evaluate that option.

Comment: And as you said in the comment to the other answer, I'm also wondering why there is no problem when doing the same with a real table. Well, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the ID column can contain NULL values. If you define the column as NOT NULL, then the index is used.

The index does not contain NULL values. But the GROUP BY must contain this data.

When you restricted the parent.id to 1 in your example, the database could use the index for the concrete value.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I tried that and it did not make a difference. `IN( NULL )` would never return rows even if I had some. Since I am using `=` to join that would also ignore `NULL` values anyways. The optimizer is also smart enough to take the index on parent which it could not if it would expect NULL values to make a difference (e.g. when using a `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` instead of `IN`)

Comment: Just tried in 19c, and I see the difference: with not nullable ID I get an index scan on idx_child instead of a table scan on child; still trying to understand it better

Comment: @Aleksej: You're right! Did not notice the difference since it's still an `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` instead of the expected `INDEX RANGE SCAN`.

Comment: @PeterLang: Exactly the same behaviour... and still trying to fully understand it

Comment: The index Fast Full Scan is executed because all values can be taken from the index.
As soon as e.g. the dummy column is added to the query, a Full Table Scan is performed again.

Comment: @ThomasKirchhoff: Of course, but the Index Range Scan would still be the right choice in my opinion. Having NOT NULL on that column should not make that difference. As I said, this query can never return NULL values, both the `IN` and the `JOIN` prevent that.

Comment: All three sentences of this answer are *orrect*, but they **do not** answert the question, because a `null` value in `id` will newer return a row in the join on `parent` and `child`. The *more relevant* 3rd sentence would be: "When you restricted the parent.id to 1 the  *predicate can be  pushed* in the subquery and therefore the `index range scan` can be used".

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yes, you are right. Because of the PL/SQL table, the values cannot be pushed to the subquery. So the Group by will be executed first. The index is not used because the NULL values would have to be grouped as well.
Another solution would be to restrict child.id IN (...) in the subquery instead of parent.id IN (...).

Comment: Yes @ThomasKirchhoff good observation. Using an *ordinary* table such as `parent.id IN ( select id from tab )` seem to work fine.

Comment: I'm still not sure why an index scan works fine when using a subquery with a real table but your answer helps to explain the difference between the TABLE ACCESS FULL and the INDEX FAST FULL. Thank you!